# What is the BigO runtime of this code snippet? Just want to confirm

Tags: big-o

This is written to get the intersection of L1 and L2.

```
while(iter1.hasNext()&&iter2.hasNext()){
        element1 = iter1.next();
        element2 = iter2.next();
        int result;
        while(element1 != null && element2 != null){
            result = element1.compareTo(element2);
            if(result == 0){
                L3.add(element1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it order (n^2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would simply be O(n).  The inner "while" loop will never repeat because the condition it depends on, `element1` and `element2` don't change inside of it.  If you ever enter that nested while loop, you'll never leave.

Comment: In fact, this algorithm doesn't provide the intersection between two sets.